# Setting custom image for UINavigationBar or title: confusion during navigation

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I found enough good examples about how to use a custom image as a background for a UINavigationBar without hiding any buttons after or during navigating between different views. However, I have the following problem I don't seem to have an answer for.

I have a UITabBarViewController object as a root controller to which I have added a number of different UINavigationControllers objects as subviews (one per tab) each initialized with a UITableViewController object as their root controller. From each table view it is possible to navigate to a child controller which displays more detailed information about the selected cell. Now the problem i have is the following:

In the navigation controller of each table view I set a custom background image. This is done by overwriting the drawRect method of UINavigationBar. When a user navigates down to the detail view of each table view, the image should be replaced with the title of the detail view. I accomplish this by using a global variable and I update this in each viewWillAppear method of every view and using an if condition inside the overwritten drawRect method. So to illustrate this with some code:

In the app delegate .h.file I declare the external variable as:

```
extern BOOL displayImage;
```

In the app delegate .m file I initialize the external variable as:

```
BOOL displayImage = TRUE;
```

For all view controllers the viewWillAppear method is implemented like:

```
// View where I want to show the image in the navigation bar
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   ...

   self.navigationItem.title = nil;      // No title
   displayImage = TRUE;
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];

   ...
} 

// View where I do NOT want to show the image in the navigation bar
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   ...

   self.title = @"Info";
   displayImage = FALSE;
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];

   ...
}

// Overwritten drawRect method of UINavigationBar
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   if (displayImage) {
      // Code that draws the image by calling drawInRect
   } else {
      // Code that just sets a black background
   }
}
```

This works great when I navigate from a table view to the detail view (child controller of the table view) and back to the parent view. However, when I navigate from a detail view to another tab of the tab bar, the title of the detail view dissapears and the image re-appears (so far so good), but when I then navigate back to the tab holding the detail view, the title of the detail view appears, but the image does not dissapear (i.e. BOTH the title and image are shown in the navigation bar). It seems like the setNeedsDisplay method is not called in this situation. During all this the external variable gets updated correctly.

Is there anybody who can tell me what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Solved the problem by just setting a black background .png instead of making the background black with CGContextFillRect when not displaying the original image. Works like expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I was also in the same situation. If I m getting your problem your image from navigation bar is not getting disappear when switching between the different tabs. So you need to create two images, one normal images another one is black image.

Use black image instead of setting black color in the else part of the drawrect method in the category. And also reset the variable in the viewWillDisappear when switching from the page instead of setting the variable on the next page. May be your problem get solved.